# axios is not working with post file data wirh new FormData()

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

My previous code for file uploading is working with jQuery Ajax call. But when I am trying to achieve the same task with Axios library then I got errors. I also search solution for that but not found. If anyone faces this issue. guide us. My previous code in Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.props.url,
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

But in my new project (ReactJs and Axios), I 'm trying to achieve the same task with Axios(v0,17.0). But I am getting the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/' from origin
>   'http://localhost:9002' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request
>   header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
>
> Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)

below code in Axios, I am using formData() to append file to eaily.

```
import axios from 'axios';

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('noteFilename', files);

axios({
    method : 'POST',
    url : this.props.url,
    data:formData,
    headers: {
        'cache': false,
        'Content-Type' : false,
        'processData': false,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'crossDomain' : true,
    },
    withCredentials: true,
}).then((response) => {
    console.log("response", response)

}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Sorry for title typo mistake it should be  "axios is not working with post file with new FormData()"

Comment: You can edit your question and remove typo! And you should edit format of your AJAX code.

Comment: CORS is something related to server not send the needed headers for OPTIONS request. Is your url same for both jQuery and react js projects. You have to check on  your server to add the needed CORS headers

Comment: Yes URL is same.

Comment: Axios is not jQuery. Read the Axios API documentation. Don't just pass it the same options you pass to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the browser sends a request to check if the api is allowed to be accessed from the browser on a different domain. Add headers to the server for the client-side to understand that it can make calls and will get a valid response for subsequent GET/POST calls.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
```

you can even restrict the domain via the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` key

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "xyz.com");
```

PS: Changes are to made on the server-side and not the client-side.

Comment: thanks, But I am uploading the file through $.ajax() this is uploaded successfully.

Comment: are you setting axios defaults or instance properties properly? they both use XHR under the hood so it shouldn't make a difference tbh @DheerajRao

Answer (score 0):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:9002' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

This is because you are trying to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the request.

It makes no sense to do that. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header which the server sets to give the client permission to pass the data to JS.

Remove that header.